# How to install Blockstack Browser on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, blockstack

### ***How do I install Blockstack browser on Ubuntu?***

I downloaded the shell script from https://blockstack.org/install and then ran `./Blockstack-for-Linux-v0.36.3.sh`

I've looked and there is not much info on the subject.

I got the following message:

```
blockstack docker launcher commands:
  install-protocol-handler -> install a protocol handler for blockstack:// links
  remove-protocol-handler -> uninstall the protocol handler for blockstack:// links
  pull  -> fetch docker containers from quay
  start -> start the blockstack browser server
  stop  -> stop the blockstack browser server

To get started, use

 $  ./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh pull
 $  ./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh install-protocol-handler
 $  ./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh start

This *requires* Docker to run.

To remove the protocol handler (the only thing 'installed' when you run this launcher):

 $  ./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh remove-protocol-handler

And this will start the environment for running the Blockstack Browser

Note: the Docker containers mount your /home/<user>/.blockstack directory
```

Yes, Docker is installed on my machine.

Comment: I think the message is giving instructions. Have you try to run it? `./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh pull`, `./Blockstack-for-Linux.sh install-protocol-handler`, etc.

Comment: If you'll notice in the very beginning, I stated that I ran the file and that was the output. That specific file name is not the one that I downloaded from the site. The file I downloaded from the official site has the version number in the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
./Blockstack-for-Linux-v0.36.3.sh pull
```

then

```
./Blockstack-for-Linux-v0.36.3.sh start
```